# Spring boot Security Always Redirecting to home.jsp

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

Currently i am using Spring Boot 1.4.0 version for my ongoing development, using spring security for authentication. Requirement is when user login for the first time need to redirect to Password reset page otherwise it should redirect to home page. Application is always redirecting home.jsp irrespective of the url configured in success handler.

Below is my configuration ,am i missing anything here

WebSecurityConfiguration

```
          http.authorizeRequests()
         .antMatchers("/resources/**","/rest/**","/log*")
         .permitAll()
         .antMatchers("/admin**").hasAuthority("admin") 
         .anyRequest()
         .authenticated()
         .and()
         .formLogin()
         .loginPage("/login")
         .successHandler(authHandler)
         .failureHandler(authFailureHandler)
         .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
         .permitAll()
         .and()
         .logout()
         .invalidateHttpSession(true)
         .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
         .permitAll()
         .and()
         .csrf().disable();
```

public class AuthSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

```
private RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();
@Override
protected void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    String isFirstTimePwd = String.valueOf(session.getAttribute("IsFirstTimeLogIn"));
    if (isFirstTimePwd.equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
    {
        redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request,response,"/firstTime");
    }
    else
    {
        redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, "/home");
    }
}
```

}

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/firstTime", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String displayFirstTimeLoginPage(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {
    return "firstTime";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView homePage(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {
    HttpSession  session = request.getSession();
    User user =(User)  session.getAttribute("User");
    return new ModelAndView("home", "loggedInUser", user);
}
```

And also i tried with implementing authenticationsuccesshandler by overriding onAuthenticationsuccess() but still redirecting home.jsp instead password reset page.

Comment: Do you try to debug find what's the value of `isFirstTimePwd.equalsIgnoreCase("true")` ?

Comment: Yes, Its going firstTime Controller mapping and redirecting Password reset page after that immediately redirecting to home.jsp, If I renamed home.jsp to index.jsp its showing file not found.

Comment: @aap: You have to override `onAuthenticationsuccess()`. Show Spring Security logs with level `DEBUG`. It will show, why you are not redirected to the right page.

Answer (score 0):

you'd better go to homePage and test if it's the firstTime or not

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView homePage(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {

    if (isFirstTimePwd.equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
        {
            redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request,response,"/firstTime");
        }

        HttpSession  session = request.getSession();
        User user =(User)  session.getAttribute("User");
        return new ModelAndView("home", "loggedInUser", user);
    }
```

Edit1 :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView homePage(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {

         HttpSession  session = request.getSession();
            User user =(User)  session.getAttribute("User");
        if (isFirstTimePwd.equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
            {
                 return new ModelAndView("firstTime", "loggedInUser", user);
            }

            return new ModelAndView("home", "loggedInUser", user);
        }
```

Comment: The problem here is Its redirecting twice , first time its redirecting reset page after that immediately its triggering next redirect To home.jsp when second time redirecting its not entering into controller Mapping. Basically its overriding.

Comment: and if we make return new ModelAndView("firstTime", "loggedInUser", user); into "if" ??  (see Edit1)